# SimpleXML Access Data

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a xml File like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
<Items>
    <Item Category="14" />
</Items>
<Events>
    <Event type="EventType">
        <Date>November 24, 2016</Date>
    </Event>
</Events>
</Data>
```

And want to get the Value "14" in the Item->Category.

I tried like that:

```
echo $xml->Items->Item[0]->{@attributes}['Category'];
```

Output is empty.

When i just do:

```
print_r($xml)
```

i get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Items] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Item] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [Category] => 14 ) ) ) [Events] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Event] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [type] => EventType ) [Date] => November 24, 2016 ) ) )
```

Then i tried:

```
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $xml, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
```

Output is:

```
Index array Array ( ) Vals array Array ( )
```

The XML is opened like that:

```
$file="test.xml";


if (file_exists($file)) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

Comment: Thanks. Output is empty :-(

Comment: Output for "Print_r($xml->Items->Item[0]->{@attributes});" is "SimpleXMLElement Object ( )"

Comment: do something like this(1st example):-http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php

Comment: Output is "Index array Array ( ) Vals array Array ( )" :-(

Answer (score 0):

you can get it with the following code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('folder/yourfile');
$xmlselect = $xml->Data;

foreach($xmlselect AS $objekt)
{
      $items = $objekt->Items->Item;
        foreach ($items as $key) {
            $itemId= $key->attributes();
        }
}
```

Maybe it will help you!